# What types of ducks are cold hardy, and do well in wetlands?

Tags: animals, farming

For a sustainable farm in Minnesota (USA), I'm looking for an egg-laying duck that won't need wing clipping, will survive a snowy winter, and will produce good eggs. What should I look into?

Comment: Rather than just down voting, can you please explain why?

Comment: Downvoting is probably because the question doesn't show any research effort. It will also help if you explain why you think this question belongs here and not on [Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com) or [Pets SE](http://pets.stackexchange.com)

Comment: sustainable farming is not pets nor biology.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't say that that's your goal.

Comment: Phone some duck farms in the neighbourhood? I think you'll have more results Googling for those than for your 'duck requirements'.

Comment: Any duck except Whistling and Black Bellied.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend.  Use it.

search **cold weather ducks**

http://thriftyhomesteader.com/2013/11/cold-ducks-keeping-ducks-in-winter.html

The above is in the Olympic mountains at 1000 feet.  Heavy snowfall.  Lows in the teens (F)  Khaki Campbells and Blue Swedish.

http://wholefedhomestead.com/what-temperature-can-a-duck-survive/

Peking Ancona ducks.  Claims -20 F temps without problems.  Tricks to keep liquid water.

Comment: For the benefit of this site, would you be willing to summarize these sites, e.g. stating the breed of duck and some reference temperature?